# webservice call with certificates fails with socket read error

Tags: jax-rs, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x, sslhandshakeexception

I connect to `REST` webservice running on server using Apache HttpClientBuilder. The client must send a certificate to validate and the server certificate is added in truststore in the client side. I specify with options `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` , `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore`.

However I get below error, any clues? I'm not sure SSL handshake is successful, but there seems to `ServerHelloDone` and `Found Certificate` in logs.

**Code**

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://testmachine.com/retrieve/path");

// add request header
request.addHeader(Constants.HTTP_HEADER_ACCEPT, Constants.MEDIA_TYPE_JSON);

// request to SERVER
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

**LOGS**

```
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 ........g...oJ..v...
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 32
0000: 14.......
0010: 5A.......
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 3
main, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
%% Invalidated:  [Session-3, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 18
0000: 02 .....@.y..A.
0010: 31 8F                                              1.
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
Apr 18, 2016 1:52:17 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://testmachine.com:443: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Apr 18, 2016 1:52:17 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://testmachine.com:443
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `keystore` is not read from the logs. I susupect that it is because my certificate inside the `keystore` is ".**p12**" format and has its own password. So I had to explicitly load the `keystore` and `truststore` and build `SSLContext` to make it working.

One important thing to note is that the `privateKeyPassword` you will have to supply the `certificate` password (and not the `keystore` password that is to protect the key entry).

```
 .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, privateKeyPassword.toCharArray())
```

Here is some part of code that explains that.

```
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    FileInputStream keyStream = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
    try {
        keyStore.load(keyStream, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to load keystore: " + ex.toString());
        return;
    } finally {
        try {
            keyStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }

    // load keystore and truststore
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(truststoreFile, truststorePassword.toCharArray(),
                    new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, privateKeyPassword.toCharArray())        
                    .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext,
            new String[] { "TLSv1" },
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
```